# defining method of class in if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I'm trying to create a class that will create objects with different methods based on an input.  The point of this is to avoid using an if statement every time the method is called.

Below is the code I thought would work, but isn't working.

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self,food_type):
        self.food_type = food_type

        if food_type == 'cookie':
            print 'this is a cookie'
            def is_awesome(self):
                print "is awesome"
        else:
            print 'this is not a cookie'
            def is_awesome(self):
                print "not awesome"

Oreo = Food('cookie')
Oreo.is_awesome()
```

The code doesn't error on the `def is_awesome(self)` statement, but instead the `Oreo.is_awesome()` line raises the error:

"AttributeError: Food instance has no attribute is_awesome".

Is there a better way to make objects with different methods? and is there a reason why the method `is_awesome` isn't callable by 'Oreo.is_awesome'?

Comment: Within `__init__ `, you could just do `self.is_awesome = food_type == "cookie"`. That is, if you want a boolean value, not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar situation where I wanted different instances of a class to have one of the methods behave differently depending on the init values but still have the same method name, and didn't want to run if/else statements at every call  to the method.

The simplest solution I found was to define a setter method that creates a pointer to the wanted behavior, and this setter method is only run once at initialization:

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self, food_type):
        self.food_type = food_type
        
        self.set_awesomeness()
    
    def is_awesome():
        return 'is awesome'

    def not_awesome():
        return 'not awesome'

    # Point to the wanted behavior
    def set_awesomeness(self):
        if self.food_type == 'cookie':
            self.awesomeness = Food.is_awesome()
        else:
            self.awesomeness = Food.not_awesome()

    def get_awesomeness(self):
        return self.awesomeness
    
cookie = Food('cookie')
cookie.get_awesomeness() # 'is awesome'

donut = Food('donut')
donut.get_awesomeness() # 'not awesome'
```

Answer (score 3):

**Is there a better way to make objects with different methods?**

Yes a way that works :) Polymorphism is a great candidate.

```
class Food:
  def is_awesome(self):
    print 'not awesome'

class Cookie(Food):
  def is_awesome(self):
    print 'is awesome'
```

**and is there a reason why the method  is_awesome isn't callable by 'Oreo.is_awesome'?**

Yes, it's not bound to the instance (conventionally called `self`) in any

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the method/function `is_awesome(self)` and then your `if's` inside it

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self,food_type):
        self.food_type = food_type

    def is_awesome(self):
         if self.food_type == 'cookie':
            print 'this is a cookie'
            print "is awesome"
         else:
            print 'this is not a cookie not awesome'
            print "not awesome"


Oreo = Food('cookie')
Oreo.is_awesome()
```

This works, tested!

Comment: Sorry I didn't indicate this, but I am aware that this way works, but I'm trying to find a way to avoid going through an if statement each time I call 'is_awesome'